# Spark-kafka streaming multiple consumer group for same topic does not work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new to kafka and spark. I have a use case, where a kafka topic need to be consumed from multiple spark streaming window.

**Topic**...

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --topic feed --partitions 10 --zookeeper xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx --replication-factor 2
```

**Code**...

```
package tech.webstar.speed

import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.{DStream, ReceiverInputDStream}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Duration, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}


/**
  * @author sasajib
  */
class FeedStream2(ssc: StreamingContext, group: String = "default") {

    def start(): Unit = {

        val kafkaStream: ReceiverInputDStream[(String, String)] = {
            KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx", group, Map("feed" -> 10))
        }

        val window: DStream[(String, String)] = kafkaStream.window(Duration(5000))
        window.foreachRDD(_.foreach(result => {
            println("<===============Window===============================>")
            println(result)
            println(">===============Window===============================<")
        }))
    }
}


object FeedStream2 extends App {
    val sparkConf: SparkConf = {
        new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("speed-layer")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
    }

    val context: SparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val ssc: StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(context, Duration(1000))
    ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
    //    context.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    //if I comment out one of these, the code works
    new FeedStream2(ssc, "group1").start()
    new FeedStream2(ssc, "group2").start()   

    sys.addShutdownHook(() => {
        ssc.stop()
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

As my understanding, given 2 window should work and consume same message, cause kafka group id is different. But none of the window work.
If I comment out one of the window the code works and print the topic message.

How can I consume same topic message with different spark streaming window?

Thanks.

> spark-streaming-kafka vesion: 1.6.2

Comment: are you using  serialize and deserialize class ? or sure records is not serialized ?

Comment: createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder] is default.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b975ec5855c46e4435e41452a1d16b09#file-kafkautils-scala

Comment: @Shakil Did you get the solution, of why you are not able to consume from different consumer groups?